# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/add-student 500 (Internal Server Error) and xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

Tags: php, database, laravel, crud

Whenever I try to update the record in laravel in 8.2.1 version this error (POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/add-student 500 (Internal Server Error) ) comes to me and when i see in console it says (
xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null ); )
two picture are also attached 1. [My Code in inside.blade.ph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGPsG.png) and second pic is of [route defined inside web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K515.png)
If someone knows the issue kindly correct me.

Comment: *500 (Internal Server Error)* means that an error occured on the server, while executing some code on the server. Usually it is an error somewhere in php code and you will have to track it down either though logs, or manually. You didi not exactly add any php code for us to help you. In future please never include code as pictures, and include it as actual code. It's very hard to read pictures. Try to follow [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guide.

Comment: The question title needs to be better formulated like: "Why do I get a Internal Server Error 500 on my local server", then you can provide the details in the question body. Instead of screenshots add actual code blocks.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please format your question and include the relevant code to analyse the problem. (Do not post pictures of code.) You might also find this article useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask